# Python: Create Every Combination of Tuples from a List of Lists Data Structure

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tuples, combinations

Is there a way to create all possible combinations of a list of lists in tuple form without resorting to nested for loops?

I have the following variable:

```
test_list = [['hugs'], ['yelling', 'fighting', 'kicking'], ['love', 'care']]
```

I want to create the following output but without using nested for loops:
[image]

Is there a way to do this?  I'd prefer not to have to import a library if possible.

Answer (score 2):

> this may help

import itertools

```
test_list = [['hugs'], ['yelling', 'fighting', 'kicking'], ['love', 'care']]
mylist = itertools.product(test_list, repeat=2)
print(list(mylist))
```

> result :
> [(['hugs'], ['hugs']), (['hugs'], ['yelling', 'fighting', 'kicking']),
> (['hugs'], ['love', 'care']), (['yelling', 'fighting', 'kicking'],
> ['hugs']), (['yelling', 'fighting', 'kicking'], ['yelling',
> 'fighting', 'kicking']), (['yelling', 'fighting', 'kicking'], ['love',
> 'care']), (['love', 'care'], ['hugs']), (['love', 'care'], ['yelling',
> 'fighting', 'kicking']), (['love', 'care'], ['love', 'care'])]